# Ansible: Access facts set by set_fact

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I need to be able to set variables using tasks in Ansible. I use set_fact for this, but cannot seem to access the fact I set with this. What is wrong with the code below:

```
- name: kludge1 
  set_fact: fake_y = "{{ [] }}" 

- name: Loop 
  debug: 
    msg: "{{ item }}" 
  with_items: "{{ fake_y }}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have spaces before and after `=`...

```
- name: kludge1 
  set_fact: fake_y="{{ [] }}"
```

Avoid `var=` shortcut syntax. Use original YAML syntax instead, it gives less errors:

```
- name: kludge1 
  set_fact:
    fake_y: "{{ [] }}"
```